# Possible to create a WSDL from request/response pairs?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a series of request / response pairs I've captured from my connections to a webservice (Microsoft Business Productivity Online Suite).  They don't publish a WSDL but these are just SOAP requests so I should be able to make them myself.

Is there an easy way to reconstruct a WSDL from these request/response pairs?  I'm trying to rebuild it by hand and it's extremely slow going.  I'd like to make sure this is even possible before going much further.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should search for XML instance to XML schema converters - somewhat heuristic tools that recreate schema from document instances. Having XML Schema you can easily regenerate WSDL using simple shell script.

Also [Spring-WS](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/) is based on request-response XSD description rather than full WSDL, so XML schema might be enough.

Answer (score -1):

WSDL and SOAP are just XML Schema, so you could use a schema-inference tool to "guess" at the WSDL by looking at example documents.  Various (usually expensive) tools will do this for you, but [trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html) is simple and free and usually makes a decent job of it.

You'll likely have to tweak the output to match reality when you try and actually use it, but it's a good starting point.